# Where can I find thorough nginx documentation?

Tags: nginx, proxy, documentation

I'd like to use nginx to serve as the proxy on our existing host when we migrate to a new server/ip address. Everywhere I've been says to use nginx for its speed.

However the documentation appears to be nearly non-existent. Lots of application guides, but nothing in depth on the nginx wiki for:

- syntax
- the `set` command

If it's any interest, I'm looking specifically to learn how to send requests to the new host so that it knows what the original host requested was. Possibly via a new header, possibly by setting a query string param.n

Comment: I think you might be confused. The set command is incredibly simple and very rarely used. For proxying decumentation you should check the proxy_pass directive, which should (ought to) talk a bit about passing headers. For syntax see the primer linked on the Configure page.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule - note the add_header